# Как правильно округлять большие отрицательные числа?

Tags: javascript, математика, округление

```js
let x = "-15 000,00";
console.log(Math.round(parseFloat(x)));
```

Возвращает -15,
а нужно -15 000

Подскажите пожалуйста способы и методы, как можно округлить большое отрицательное число

Comment: Не используйте пробел в переменной `x`. Также JS использует не запятую, а точку, пример: `-15000.42`

Comment: Большое спасибо! Дело в том, что переменную "x" я получаю из массива именно в таком виде. Буду заменять запятую на точку и убирать лишний пробел

Comment: Это можно сделать так: `x.replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/,/, '.')`